# Use the equivalences to transform the following wff into a CNF

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having trouble figuring out how we are arriving at this particular solution

Use equivalences to transform the following wff into a CNF. (Conjuctive Normal Form).
$(P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow P)$

So the solution says:

P → (Q → P) ≡ P → (¬Q ∨ P) **//What rule are we using here that allows us to do this step?**

≡ ¬P ∨ (¬Q ∨ P) **//Same question for here**

≡ ¬P ∨ ¬Q ∨ P **I understand this we are just removing parenthesis**

≡ ¬P ∨ P ∨ ¬Q **//Associative rule**

≡ True ∨ ¬Q  **//I for get this rule, but true $\vee$ any thing is always True**

≡ True **//ok**

≡ ¬P ∨ P **//Yeah where the hell did this come from lol**

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should note that $A \to B \equiv \lnot A \lor B$ (this can be verified with a truth table), so applying this twice gives the first two lines.

Comment: I see. What about the last part $\neg P \vee P$? Shouldn't the final answer be $\equiv True \vee \neg Q =$ True?

Comment: @Shammy I think they just want conjunctive normal form... I'm not sure myself